# Hibernate properties not found, not needed for Spring-MVC though

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a maven project which uses Spring-MVC directly to connect with hibernate and hibernate dialect and other information is specified within the servlet. I am using POSTGRES. I have 2 questions, Do I have to create a database which is to be used by the application? And as per what I read, when using Spring-MVC directly with hibernate, it is not necessary to have a seperate hibernate.properties file, but I still have the error. I am posting the error code and the servlet file. Kindly let me know. Thank you.

Apache tomcat error log :

```
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:17 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:mvcdispatcher' did not find a matching property.
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:17 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:17 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 419 ms
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep 08 13:33:19 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 151 ms
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Sep 08 13:33:19 CEST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/remove/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.removePerson(int)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/person/add],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.addPerson(com.journaldev.spring.model.Person)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/persons],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.listPersons(org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/edit/{id}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String com.journaldev.spring.PersonController.editPerson(int,org.springframework.ui.Model)
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.Version - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.6.Final}
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder - HHH000422: Disabling contextual LOB creation as connection was null
INFO : org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator - HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
INFO : org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 1155 ms
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:20 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 08, 2014 1:33:20 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2845 ms
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/mvcdispatcher/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'appServlet'
```

Servlet-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernatedb" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="postgres" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="asayhk2787" />

    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
    <beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.journaldev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
                </beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="personDAO" class="com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="personService"
        class="com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl">
        <beans:property name="personDAO" ref="personDAO"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.journaldev.spring" />

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <beans:property name="sessionFactory"
            ref="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" />
    </beans:bean>


</beans:beans>
```

2nd Error message. For some reason, The program/Eclipse keeps swapping between these 2 error msgs.

```
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:05 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:mvcdispatcher' did not find a matching property.
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:05 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 452 ms
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.55
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Sep 08 13:52:07 CEST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 160 ms
Sep 08, 2014 1:52:07 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Mon Sep 08 13:52:07 CEST 2014]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
ERROR: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl] for bean with name 'personDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl] for bean with name 'personDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl
Related cause: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl] for bean with name 'personService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:658)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:672)
```

.classpath file for the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry excluding="com/journaldev/spring/model/" kind="src" output="target/classes" path="src/main/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="main/java/|main/|test/java/|test/resources/|main/java/com/journaldev/spring/model/" kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry excluding="java/|java/com/journaldev/spring/model/" kind="src" path="src/main"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/java">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="optional" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry excluding="**" kind="src" output="target/test-classes" path="src/test/resources">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.dependency" value="/WEB-INF/lib"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Kindly let me know what I should do. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernate just tries to load the `hibernate.properties` file during initialization, if the file is not present then it gives a message saying the file is not available.

```
INFO : org.hibernate.cfg.Environment - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
```

This is just a logger `INFO` message not an `ERROR`

**Update:**

The second stacktrace just says the classes are not available during run-time, so check if you are including the classes properly while you are deploying your application.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.journaldev.spring.dao.PersonDAOImpl

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.journaldev.spring.service.PersonServiceImpl
```

Also from first stacktrace it seems you have not placed the jar file that contains the Driver class, this is the error that says the Diver class is missing:

```
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl - HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : Cannot load JDBC driver class 'org.postgresql.Driver'
INFO : org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: Hi Chaitanya, Well, the code doesn't run. Any ideas. And now it changed the error messages. For some reason, it keeps swapping between these 2 error messages. Don't know why. I am editing my original post to add the 2nd error post.

Comment: @Kernelfreak, updated my post, looks like you are not adding classes and Jar files properly while deploying your application

Comment: The classes are there. I will look for the jar, that I thought maven will take care of. I can see the classes. I am posting classpath in the original post.

Comment: ok, so it is a maven project and classes are available at `target/classes` directory which is correct for maven. Now how you are deploying the application? as this is a spring mvc you will have WAR/EAR so check your WAR/EAR and see if the classes are present.

Comment: All the classes are available in the WAR file. I tried both ways, running directly from within the eclipse on Server, which is tomcat, didn't work. So I created a WAR, manually went to localhost manager app and deployed the war file. Same error.

Comment: can you paste your WAR file structure and the location where the classes are going, because if the files are present the server will not complain with this errors.

Comment: Here is the war file link : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1994132/mvcmanager.war

Comment: I tried to deploy your WAR file in my tomcat server but I did not get any errors saying ClassNotFound exception, also there are no issues with location of classes in WAR, so I think the WAR file which you are deploying in server is different from the WAR that have shared with me.

Comment: I don't know what went wrong with the project, but I created a new one and copied the java classes and all. It works now. Was just creating some tables. On that point, can you help me with PostGRES syntax, I am familiar with mysql, but not with postgres. Also, should I paste the .sql file within the project or not? Here is the mysql db function I am trying to convert to postgres. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1994132/Person.sql

Comment: I am not familiar with postgresql, please use stackoverflow for your queries on that.

Comment: Sure. Thanks man. Can you just tell me if I should add the .sql file within the project. Thanks.

Comment: there is no use of adding .sql files in WAR unless you specially do something with the file during initialization or ask hibernate to read the file and do some operation.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the logs that you have put in the question, this looks more like a class loading issue. Spring is trying to initialize the bean with PersonDAOImpl as you have defined in the context file but its not able to locate the class.

Please make sure that the class is available, may be its a part of a separate jar and that jar is not present at the run time.

Comment: It is a MVC model. Can you please tell me where should I load the class? They are alreaddy there in the package. Also in the war file.

Comment: Can you please stop the server and remove the war file and unwared folder, paste the war file again in webapps and start the server?